# How to show HTML Table Data in Percentage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML Table which is having some Data in numeric form, I want to convert them into percentage.

My Html table has data having Total in one column and its data in same row what i a trying to achieve is to convert the nos into percentage

this is what my table is populating data now

**Snippet**

```js
var data=[
  {
    "amount": 518212,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104801,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 138151,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  }
 
]


let formatData = function (data) {
        let billdates = [];
        let outlets = [];
        data.forEach(element => {
            if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
                billdates.push(element.billdate);
            }
            if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
                outlets.push(element.outlet);
            }
        });
        return {
            data: data,
            billdates: billdates,
            outlets: outlets,
            
        };
    };

        let renderTable = function (data) {
        billdates = data.billdates;
        outlets = data.outlets;
        data = data.data;
        let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
        let table = document.createElement("table");
        let thead = document.createElement("thead");
        let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
        let th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = "Bill_____Date";
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
        let grandTotal = 0;
        let outletWiseTotal = {};
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = "Total1";
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
        outlets.forEach(element => {
            th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = element;
            
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
            outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
            data.forEach(el => {
                if (el.outlet == element) {
                    outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
                }
            });
            grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
        });
        thead.appendChild(headerRow);
        headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = "Total";
        headerRow.appendChild(th);

        outlets.forEach(element => {
            th = document.createElement("th");
                     //   console.log(outletWiseTotal[element]);
                       var test= ((outletWiseTotal[element]/grandTotal)*100);
                       var fix=test.toFixed(2)+"%";
                      console.log(fix)    // this one is giving me right result for row "Total"
            th.innerHTML = fix;
            th.classList.add("text-right");
                        //ol wise total  
            
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
        });
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = "100%" //grandTotal
        th.classList.add("text-right"); 
                        // grand total
        headerRow.insertBefore(th , headerRow.children[1] );
        thead.appendChild(headerRow);
        table.appendChild(thead);

         let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
            billdates.forEach(element => {
         let row = document.createElement("tr");  
            td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerHTML = element;
            row.appendChild(td);
            let total = 0;
            outlets.forEach(outlet => {
                let el = 0;
                data.forEach(d => {
                    if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
                        total += parseInt(d.amount);
                        el = d.amount;
                                  
                    }
                              
                });
                           td.classList.add("text-right");                       
                           var test1= ((el/total)*100);
                           console.log(test1)     //this one is giving some wrong result for first column it is giving 100% which is wrong
                  td = document.createElement("td");
                           td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
                           row.appendChild(td);
            });
      
            td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerHTML = "100%"  //total date wise
            td.classList.add("text-right");
              console.log(total) // total date wise
                          
      row.insertBefore(td , row.children[1] );
            tbody.appendChild(row);
        });

        table.appendChild(tbody);
        tbl.innerHTML = "";
        tbl.appendChild(table);
        table.classList.add("table");
        table.classList.add("table-striped");
        table.classList.add("table-bordered");
    }
let formatedData = formatData(data);
         renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="tbl"></div>
```

what i am trying to achieve is something like this

[image: this is what i am trying to achieve]

i know how to convert the no into percentage using JavaScript but in this table not able to achieve as what i need

- i have edited my snippet in which for first row i am getting right result but for second row 1st column it is giving `100`
- Please check my snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

i have created a new variable inside the loop `let tempTotal = 0;` and follow this condition `if (d.billdate == element){ tempTotal += parseInt(d.amount); }` now use temTotal to calculate the percentage

```js
var data = [{
    amount: 518212,
    billdate: '2018-08-04',
    outlet: 'JAYANAGAR',
  },
  {
    amount: 104801,
    billdate: '2018-08-04',
    outlet: 'MALLESHWARAM',
  },
  {
    amount: 138151,
    billdate: '2018-08-04',
    outlet: 'KOLAR',
  },
]


let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Bill_____Date";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = element;

    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
  });
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    //   console.log(outletWiseTotal[element]);
    const test = (outletWiseTotal[element] / grandTotal) * 100
    const fix = test.toFixed(2) + "%"
    console.log(fix)
    th.innerHTML = fix;
    th.classList.add("text-right");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "100%";
  th.classList.add("text-right");

  /*  console.log(grandTotal);*/
  // headerRow.appendChild(th);
  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);
    let total = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      let tempTotal = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          el = d.amount;
        }
        if (d.billdate == element) {
          tempTotal += parseInt(d.amount);
        }
      });
      var test1 = ((el / tempTotal) * 100);
      var fix = test1.toFixed(2) + "%";
      console.log(test1.toFixed(2))
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = fix;
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    /*console.log("row is : " , row.children )*/
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = "100%";
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    // row.appendChild(td);
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="tbl"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is first group your data by date and use that transform data to create your table. it will look something like this:

```
const transformData = {}
//this will group your data by dates
data.forEach(data => {
  if(!transformData[data.billdate]) {
    transformData[data.billdate] = [];
  }
  transformData[data.billdate].push(data);
});

for(let date in transformData) {
  // this will calcualte total amount for that date
  const total = transformData[date].reduce((total, val) => {
    return total + val.amount;
  }, 0);
  transformData[date].forEach(data => {
    // here you can calculate percentage and populate your table
  })
}
```

Comment: i am already grouping my data..by grouping according to what you suggest it will change my whole code..can't you suggest me any help as i am populating my table ,look at my snippet